# Using vb.net, how can I pass empty arrays to a subroutine that will then populate the array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I want to pass an **empty** arrays to a subroutine that will then populate the arrays. The arrays are passed as Ref.

Getting: Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array.

```
    ' String Arrays.
    Dim strFileNames() As String
    Dim strFileContents() As String

    LoadInstallFiles(iOperatingSystemId, "Boot-Config", strFileNames(), strFileContents())

    Protected Sub LoadInstallFiles(ByVal iOperatingSystemId As Integer, ByVal strFileType As String, ByRef strFileNamesByRef() As String, ByRef strFileContentByRef() As String)       

    ' Do stuff to populate the arrays.

    End Sub
```

Comment: It might be better to make it a function returning an array of the data it finds/acquires.  If you have parallel arrays (Names and Contents) have it return a List(Of Thing) or an array of them

Comment: (arrays are a *vile* choice for this sort of thing because the calling code cannot usually know how large to make them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... slightly different solution using List Of

```
Module Module1

Private ListOfNamesContents As New List(Of TestClass)
Sub Main()
    Dim iOperatingSystemId As Integer = 0
    LoadInstallFiles(iOperatingSystemId, "Boot-Config", ListOfNamesContents)
' Now your ListOfNamesContents List should have 1 item in it added from the call to LoadInstallFiles sub
End Sub

Friend Sub LoadInstallFiles(ByVal iOperatingSystemId As Integer, ByVal strFileType As String, iListOfNamesContents As List(Of TestClass))

    ' Do stuff to populate the iListOfNamesContents.

    iListOfNamesContents.Add(New TestClass With {.FileContents = "Test FileContents", .FileNames = "Test FileNames"})

End Sub

End Module


Class TestClass

Private _FileNames As String
Public Property FileNames() As String
    Get
        Return _FileNames
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _FileNames = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _FileContents As String
Public Property FileContents() As String
    Get
        Return _FileContents
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _FileContents = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Should give you some ideas.... Hope that helps....

Comment: From all the tips before yours, I came up with what you are suggesting but pass a list of structure. However, I may change it to a pass a list of class like you have. Thanks....and thanks everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use arrays, you need to `ReDim` them to the appropriate size, and then populate them, in `LoadInstallFiles`.  When you pass them to `LoadInstallFiles`, don't use parentheses - just use the variable name.

```vb
' String Arrays.
Dim strFileNames() As String = Nothing
Dim strFileContents() As String = Nothing

LoadInstallFiles(iOperatingSystemId, "Boot-Config", strFileNames, strFileContents)

Protected Sub LoadInstallFiles(ByVal iOperatingSystemId As Integer, ByVal strFileType As String, ByRef strFileNamesByRef() As String, ByRef strFileContentByRef() As String)       

    ReDim strFileNamesByRef(4)
    ReDim strFileContentByRef(4)

    strFileNamesByRef(0) = "F1"
    strFileNamesByRef(1) = "F2"
    strFileNamesByRef(2) = "F3"
    strFileNamesByRef(3) = "F4"
    strFileNamesByRef(4) = "F5"

    strFileContentByRef(0) = "C1"
    strFileContentByRef(1) = "C2"
    strFileContentByRef(2) = "C3"
    strFileContentByRef(3) = "C4"
    strFileContentByRef(4) = "C5"

End Sub
```